# PHP Shuffling and inside a PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, variables, html-table

I have a problem in Shuffling my quiz. Is there any other way of doing this? Please bear with me I'm just new to PHP.

It's show as error of:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Is there anyway of shuffling this?

```
<?php

              $a="<tr><td >1. <input type='radio' name='answer' value='optiona' <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'review')==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'answered')==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),'optiona')==0 ){echo 'checked';} ?>> <? php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optiona'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr><br>"
              $b="<tr><td >2. <input type='radio' name='answer' value='optionb' <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'review')==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'answered')==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),'optionb')==0 ){echo 'checked';} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optionb'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr><br>"
              $c="<tr><td >3. <input type='radio' name='answer' value='optionc' <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'review')==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'answered')==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),'optionc')==0 ){echo 'checked';} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optionc'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr><br>"
              $d="<tr><td >4. <input type='radio' name='answer' value='optiond' <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'review')==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'answered')==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),'optiond')==0 ){echo 'checked';} ?>> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optiond'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr>"

              $my_array = array($a,$b,$c,$d);

                shuffle($my_array);
                print_r($my_array[0].$my_array[1].$my_array[2].$my_array[3]);
              ?>
```

Comment: You have some errors there. Each string line in $a, $b, $c, $d doesn't end with `;`. Also, `<?php` is not accepted in double quotes.

Comment: Also take a good look at the syntax highlighting. Not all of these strings are proper strings. Make sure the code itself works before you start shuffling it.

Comment: Also you are including <?php inside <?php tag.

Comment: @machineaddict that is absolutely not true, you can use php in double quotes. In this case I would just totally fix up your variables first. Remove the php stuff in it. Also if you wanna print_r an array just do print_r($array);

Comment: @user3122479, `can use` and `not accepted` are different sentence.

Comment: @vp_arth okay my bad then. I thought he meant that it wouldn;t work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a="<tr><td >1. <input type='radio' name='answer' value='optiona' <?php if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'review')==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'answered')==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),'optiona')==0 ){echo 'checked';} ?>><? php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optiona'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></input></td></tr><br>";
```

Try changing this to:

```
$a = "<tr><td >1. <input type='radio' name='answer' value='optiona' ";

if((strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'review')==0 ||strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['answered'],ENT_QUOTES),'answered')==0)&& strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['stdanswer'],ENT_QUOTES),'optiona')==0 ){
    $a .= "'checked'";
}

$a .= '>'.htmlspecialchars_decode($r['optiona'],ENT_QUOTES)."</input></td></tr><br>";
```

In PHP, `.` is the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) (adds text to strings)